# If $f$ is uniformly continuous then show $ \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x+h)-f(x)|=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, solution-verification

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be uniformly continuous. I want to show that
>   $$
> \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x+h)-f(x)|=0.\tag{1}
> $$

By the uniform continuity, given $\varepsilon >0$, there is $\delta >0$ such that whenever $|h| < \delta$ we get
$$
| f ( x + h ) - f ( x ) | < \varepsilon \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
It follows that whenever $|h| < \delta$
$$
\sup_{ x \in \mathbb{R} } | f ( x + h ) - f ( x ) | \leq \varepsilon.
$$
Therefore
$$
\limsup_{ h \rightarrow 0} \sup_{ x \in \mathbb{R} } | f ( x + h) - f ( x)| \leq \varepsilon,
$$
and as $\varepsilon\downarrow 0$, we get $(1)$.

---

My questions are:

1. Are all the steps above correct?
2. Is there some well-known result which can be applied here immediately?

Comment: This looks correct to me.

Comment: Although it's trivial (I'm not sure the level of rigor you need), by the same as the last step, you show that the lim inf of the sup is zero, showing that the lim of the sup is zero.

Comment: @L-- That supposed property of uniform continuity is nonsense.  $f(x)=|x|$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich How is that a counterexample? $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left||x+h|-|x|\right|$ becomes smaller and approaches $0$ as $h$ gets closer to $0$.

Comment: @bjorn93 It's  not a counterexample to the statement in the question. It's a counterexammple to something that "L" said in a comment - I don't recall  exactly what, the comment's been deleted.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sorry about that. I didn't understand you were referring to a comment.